# Can I use Bluemix devops services with a dedicated Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, private-cloud

I'm trying to add a dedicated Bluemix instance to my deploy stage in devops services as a general cloud foundry source. Can authenticate and select space but not save the settings... Are the devops service working with a dedicated Bluemix?

Answer (score 2):

DevOps services isn't currently working in dedicated, but it's high on our priority list (backlog).  If your interested in giving us some feedback on what we're thinking reach out to me and we can share what's going on behind the scenes.

- Offering Manager for DevOps Services

Answer (score 0):

The next evolution of Bluemix DevOps Services will allow to go dedicated. Read more at https://developer.ibm.com/devops-services/2016/06/16/open-toolchain-with-ibm-bluemix-devops-services/.
It is available already in Bluemix public US-South as an experiment.

Comment: Please try to add as much as information in your answer. Adding external links would be wrong, if that link content is deleted or change the content.